# How to avoid XML namespace collisions when using res-auto in Android Layouts

Tags: android, xml, namespaces

Most sources I've read regarding custom layout attributes used in Android XML layout files say that you should declare a custom namespace, usually "app", like so:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

If my understanding is correct, this creates a namespace that allows you to reference any custom attributes defined in either your own custom views or in views defined in any included libraries.  This namespace is separate from the usual "android" namespace that contains all base widgets and views contained in the android SDK.

How does one avoid namespace collisions within the "app" namespace if you are using custom views from multiple libraries?   For example, say "library1" defines a custom view "Lib1View1" which has an attribute "color".  "library2" defined a custom view "Lib2View1" which also has an attribute "color".  when one references `app:color`, how are namespace collisions avoided?

Perhaps the res-auto is context-aware enough to detect the local tag (i.e. in a `<com.library1.Lib1View1>` tag, the `app:color` attribute only refers to the library1's tag), but what about when tags are inherited from a parent layout?  For example, if the widget is contained in a layout such a `ConstraintLayout`, then the widget will have all sorts of `app:layout_*` tags associated with it.  However, it is conceivable that one would have a custom view that also has a `layout_*` tag.  Which tag then takes precedence?

Is there a way to explicitly define separate namespaces for custom libraries?  i.e.

```
xmlns:custom1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-lib1"
xmlns:custom2="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-lib2"
```